# Why $End(E)→End(T_p(E)) $ is a ring hom?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be elliptic curve and $φ$ be isogeny from $E$ to $E$.
$φ$ induces $Z_p$-linear map $φ_p$.

Why $End(E)→End(T_p(E))$ ,$φ→φ_p$ is  a ring hom?

Comment: Try replacing $E$ with  $\Bbb{Q/Z}$.

Comment: Can you convince yourself that $\varphi$ induces a homomorphism $E[p^n]\to E[p^n]$ for all $n$?